# Is there any way to achieve partial JSP rendering in Spring MVC without using AJAX or Tiles

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am wondering whether there is any way to achieve partial JSP rendering in Spring 3 MVC without using AJAX or Tiles?

My web application consists of several JSP pages which are combined together using the `<%@ include file="a.jsp"/>` directive. What I want is not to load all the data from the server in every request. I know that this is possible with Ajax or Tiles but that requires major refactoring of the application.

If there is such an alternative, how will it behave in terms of performance compared with the standard Ajax approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core technique required for partial page rendering is ajax. There are no alternatives to ajax. You can however throw in an Ajax oriented JavaScript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to simplify Ajax actions and HTML DOM traversions. It should be relatively easy to progressively enhance an existing "legacy" webapplication by just adding the necessary scripts without changing anything of the HTML markup as long as your HTML markup is written in a proper and semantic manner with the right element IDs and class names. Otherwise it's still just a matter of adding element IDs and class names at the right places.

Comment: Thanks for the reply BalusC. <br.>                                     The problem with standard jQuery/json approach is that even though the markup of the application is quite well developed still we need to convert all the JSPs to the corresponding javascript/jquery. Our team is not very experienced in javascript and thats why we ARE looking for a "JSP-like" approach. There are a few possibilities we thought about. 1)

Comment: Why do you still think that you need to convert everything? Do you want your web application to stop working when JS is disabled on client? Surely not, right? Just add JS as a progressive enhancement while untouching your well-working server side code.

Comment: There are a few possibilities we thought about. 1) Use an Ajax tag library 2) Use a combination of Spring MVC and http based caching.  3) Provide our caching mechanism on the server side in a way to only load the necessary data per request. But still I agree with you that a jquery/json approach which of course will be implemented progressively and without removing the existing JSPs is the best solution.